# Ensuring uniqueness on a varchar greater than 255 in MYSQL/InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table which contains URLs, some of which are longer than 255 characters. I want to impose a uniqueness constraint on the URL column, but MySQL isn't letting me create a key on the URL. I'm using an InnoDB/UTF8 table. From what I understand it's using multiple bytes per character with a limit of 766 bytes for the key (in InnoDB).

What is an elegant way of keeping the rows unique based on URL?

Comment: Hi Vijay - consider accepting Andre Dalcher's answer below. It's a neater way of doing things in the latest versions of MySQL, and unutbu acknowledges that it's a nicer solution at the top of their answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MySQL 5.7 or newer, see [Andre Dalcher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024314/190597) for a nicer way using generated columns.

---

You could use a [SHA1 hash](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) of the url as the unique key. There is a chance that two urls have the same hash, but the probability of that is so ridiculously small, that for practical purposes this method should work fine.

---

You could also set up a trigger so the `hash` column is computed automatically whenever you INSERT:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON foo
FOR EACH ROW SET
    NEW.hash = SHA1(NEW.url)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the solution I'm going to go with. It's a bit annoying because I occasionally want to insert things into the database manually, but I think it's the right approach.

Comment: Oh wow, hadn't thought of the trigger. That's awesome, thanks!

Comment: Another question for you unutbu: When I do an insert now, with a duplicate key I have SQL to handle it: INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id. The strange thing is it tells me that this command is inserting *two* rows into the table. I'm a bit confused by this. No extra row is created, which is correct, so I'm confused why it would be inserting two rows. Is this somehow related to the trigger?

Comment: Yes, I see this same behavior, but it is not due to the trigger. I quote [from the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), `"With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated."`

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 5.7.6 or later, you can do this using a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) containing a hash of the column that you want to place the uniqueness constraint on.

Generated columns are `VIRTUAL` by default, meaning that the values are never stored on disk. Virtual columns can only be indexed in versions of MySQL >= 5.7.8 using the InnoDB engine; for MyISAM or for older versions of MySQL you would have to use a `STORED` column.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE url_hash_test (
    ->   url TEXT,
    ->   url_hash VARCHAR(32) AS (md5(url)),
    ->   UNIQUE(url_hash)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO url_hash_test SET url='http://example.com';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO url_hash_test SET url='http://example.com';
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'a9b9f04336ce0181a08e774e01113b31' for key 'url_hash'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the URLs into 2 or more columns and make the combination `(URLpart1, URLpart2, ..., URLpartN)` unique. The maximum allowed index length will then be raised from 767 to 3072 bytes. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE atest
( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
, a VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
, b VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
, c VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
, d VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
, PRIMARY KEY (id)
, UNIQUE INDEX url_idx (a,b,c,d)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

Comment: Yes. I would use the hostname part for the first key column.

Comment: This would work (in the limited subset of scenarios where you have a string field that needs a maximum longer than 767 but less than 3072), but is a pretty ugly hack.